# Single Java Random number trying to get the fixed range

Tags: java, random, ide, bluej

I'm trying to generate a random number generator that has a fixed 1-100 range being `int min = 1` and `int max = 100`. I managed to get this code so far. Using BlueJ as the environment.

```
import java.util.Random; 

public class RandomNumber { 
    public static int getRandomNumberInts(int min, int max) { 
        Random random = new Random(); 
        return random.ints(min,(max+1)).findFirst().getAsInt(); 
    }
}
```

Is there any other way I can get a fixed number within my range without the need to enter the range myself?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: you seem to have forgotten to actually post your code.

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Comment: import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumber
{
    public static int getRandomNumberInts(int min, int max)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.ints(min,(max+1)).findFirst().getAsInt();
}
}

Comment: sorry its a bit messy idk why it wont let me post earlier

Comment: what do you meam by `without the need to enter the range myself`?  How is your program going to know the range if you don't tell it?

Comment: @Bentaye meaning it will automatically give me a random number when i call the method instead of having to manually fill in the range all the time

Answer (score 0):

You could pass your bounds to the constructor then the `RandomNumber` object know them and you can just call your method without parameters. But your method can not be static anymore.

```
public class RandomNumber {

    private Random random;
    private int minBound;
    private int maxBound;

    public RandomNumber(int minBound, int maxBound) {
        this.random = new Random();
        this.minBound = minBound;
        this.maxBound = maxBound;
    }

    public int getRandomNumberInts() {
        return random.ints(minBound, (maxBound + 1))
                     .findFirst()
                     .getAsInt(); 
    }
}
```

Then you call it this way

```
RandomNumber rn = new RandomNumber(1, 100);
System.out.println(rn.getRandomNumberInts());
System.out.println(rn.getRandomNumberInts());    
System.out.println(rn.getRandomNumberInts());    
System.out.println(rn.getRandomNumberInts());
```